# Url.Action returning incorrect URL for webapi action with Route attrubute

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a problem with the behaviour of Url.Action();

I have a webapi where all controllers require explicit route prefix attribute and all actions require a route attribute.

I register my routes in the WebApiConfig.cs

```
 var constraintResolver = new DefaultInlineConstraintResolver()
            {
                ConstraintMap =
                {
                    ["apiVersion"] = typeof( ApiVersionRouteConstraint )
                }
            };
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(constraintResolver);
```

I have currently commented out the line below, but (because) it did not change the incorrect behaviour:

```
  //config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "DefaultApi", 
 //routeTemplate: "api/v{version:apiVersion}/{controller}/{action}/{id}", defaults: new {id = RouteParameter.Optional});
```

My controllers look as follows:

```
 [RoutePrefix("api/v{version:apiVersion}/programs")]
 public class ProgramsController : ApiController
 {
    [HttpGet, Route("{telemetryKey}/versions/latest")]
    public async Task<LatestVersionResponse> GetLatestVersionInfo(Guid telemetryKey)
    {
        // serious business logic
    }

 }
```

I expect that `'@Url.Action("GetLatestVersionInfo", "Programs", new { telemetryKey = Guid.Parse("43808405-afca-4abb-a92a-519489d62290") })'`

should return `/api/v1/programs/43808405-afca-4abb-a92a-519489d62290/versions/latest`

however, I get `/Programs/GetLatestVersionInfo?telemetryKey=43808405-afca-4abb-a92a-519489d62290` instead. So, my routeprefix and route attributes are ignored.

Swagger correctly discovers my routes and I can validate that requests to the expected routes work OK - it's only the Url.Action() that is confused.

[image]

What can be wrong...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems there were a few things wrong.

**Wrong helper:**
I should be using the Url.HttpRouteUrl for generating API links from a razor view (Url.Link is for generating link from within API controllers)

**Conflict with aspnet-api-versioning** library
For some reason (perhaps a bug?) the prefix that I have on the controller (`apiVersion` variable) breaks the URL helper mechanism.

For now, I have ditched the aspnet-api-versioning library, but created an issue on their github repo, in case its a bug.

Since I really hate the idea of creating and maintaing magic strings, so I took the following approach - each controller has a public static class which contains const values for the route names:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/v1/developers")]
public class DevelopersController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet, Route("{developerId}/programs", Name = Routes.GetPrograms)]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Program>> GetPrograms(Guid developerId){}

    public static class Routes
    {
        public const string GetPrograms = nameof(DevelopersController) +"."+ nameof(DevelopersController.GetPrograms);
    }
}
```

Now that can be used from a razor controller in a simple and relatively safe manner:

`@Url.HttpRouteUrl(DevelopersController.Routes.GetPrograms, new { developerId = /* uniquest of guids */})`

A bit better than magic strings. I've also added a bunch of unit tests for controllers where I validate that each route is unique and proper and that the routes class only contains routes for the action it contains.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

Name your route:

```
[HttpGet, Route("{telemetryKey}/versions/latest", Name="LatestVersionInfoRoute")]
    public async Task<LatestVersionResponse> GetLatestVersionInfo(Guid telemetryKey)
    {
        // serious business logic
    }
```

Use Url.Link method:

```
@Url.Link("LatestVersionInfoRoute", new { telemetryKey = Guid.Parse("43808405-afca-4abb-a92a-519489d62290") })
```

Comment: I have 100 actions on all controllers... does this means I need to create 100 named routes and maintain those 100 magic strings with route names?

Comment: I believe so. Also, if you want to get relative url then use `@Url.Route`. `@Url.Link` will give you absolute url.

Comment: You can check the code of UrlHelper class at github https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/Routing/UrlHelper.cs

Comment: Actually, I tried the approach with the named route, but it returns an empty string.